Update .NET Core from 2.2 to 3.0 - Endpoint Routing not working
Application is an ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC web app with razor pages and some controller functions. After updating to 3.0, the razor pages work fine, but I'm not able to access my MVC endpoints. When I attempt to access an endpoint, I'm seeing the html of the login screen sent back instead of the desired data structure. This was working in ASP.NET Core 2.2.
Startup.cs:
app.UseRouting();   //Added for 3.0
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCookiePolicy();

// Removed 2.2
// app.UseMvc(routes =>
// {
//    routes.MapRoute(
//        name: "default",
//        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
// });

// Added for 3.0
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));

In .NET Core 2.2, navigating to
https://{mydomainname}/warhouse/orderlist

returned a nice little dataset. In .NET Core 3.0, I'm seeing the login screen as if I'd typed in https://{mydomainname}

Are you aware that .NET Core 3.0 went out of support 4 years ago?

Have you added app.UseAuthorization()? You need to check if the browser is correctly sending the authentication cookie. You can check this in the browser's developer tools by clicking on the 'Application' tab, then the 'Storage' tab, and looking at the cookies.

Your code here:
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapRazorPages());
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"));

might actually be overwriting instead of adding endpoints
try this instead:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default", 
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});


Yup, I've had it both ways.  Does not appear to change anything.

If you just remove the references to MapControllerRoute do you get the same behavior?
